# Conditional formatting in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

```py
plt.figure(facecolor='#b1cef2')
plt.suptitle('Traceroute data for Australia (Hop v RTT)', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
plt.subplot(131)
plt.bar(mar4Data_hops_AUS, mar4Data_avg_AUS, label='RTT', color=my_colors_AUS)
plt.title('March 4 Data')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(132)
plt.bar(mar5Data_hops_AUS, mar5Data_avg_AUS, label='RTT', color=my_colors_AUS)
plt.title('March 5 Data')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.subplot(133)
plt.bar(mar6Data_hops_AUS, mar6Data_avg_AUS, label='RTT', color=my_colors_AUS)
plt.title('March 6 Data')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I want to put a text where y = 0 or the bar is no shown in the graph:

[image]

Comment: did you try `plt.text` or `plt.annotate`?

Comment: @PaulH no I haven't. I was trying to come with a dynamic solution so that for each bar where y=0, it will show a static text (request timed out)

Comment: Try both of those function first, and then edit your question to focus on a specific problem